# Restrictions needed on ADT for totality

Tags: type-theory, inductive-datatypes, abstract-data-types

In the paper [Total Functional Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.364&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by D.A. Turner three rules are given for a programming language to remain total:

1. complete case analysis
2. covariant type recursion (type constructor should not appear in negative position in a constructor argument)
3. structural recursion

But with these rules I can still have an infinite loop:

```
data Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
data Bad r = Bad (r -> r)

bad :: Fix Bad -> Fix Bad
bad b =
  case b of
    Fix t ->
      case t of
        Bad f -> f b

nonTotal = bad (Fix (Bad bad))
```

Where is my mistake? Should all type variables also only appear covariantly? Or is the "covariant type recursion" condition more strict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint

> 2. covariant type recursion (type constructor should not appear in negative position in a constructor argument)

excludes this

```
data Bad r = Bad (r -> r)
                  ^    ^--- positive position
                  ^-------- negative position
```

Indeed, *all* the occurrences of `r` must appear in positive position.

> Should all type variables also only appear covariantly?

Yes, precisely.

Essentially, your `Fix Bad` tries to generate a type $T$ isomorphic to $T \to T$. If we had that, we would have a model of the untyped $\lambda$ calculus, where terms are not normalizing ("terminating") in general.

Indeed, to apply any two terms $x, y : T$ we can exploit the isomorphism to treat $x$ as if $x : T\to T$, at which point the application $x y$ becomes feasible. As a special case, we also obtain $xx$, hence $\Omega = (\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.xx)$ which is the archetypal non normalizing term.

To conclude let me point out that, in some advanced calculi with dependent types, covariant recursion is not enough, and you need an even stricter constraint called "strict positivity". Without that, [contradictions arise](http://vilhelms.github.io/posts/why-must-inductive-types-be-strictly-positive/). In Haskell-like languages, covariance (and the other constraints you mention) should suffice.

Comment: Thanks! So that means Fix is still valid? And the type "data Mu f = Mu (forall t. (f t -> t) -> t) is also valid (f only occurs positively). Correct?

Comment: @Labbekak No, `Fix` is not valid, either. `Fix f` is defined as `f (Fix f)` which is not a positive occurrence of `Fix f` (nor a negative one). Coq would reject that. After all it could be negative or positive or neither depending on what `f` is, and we do not know that at this point. `Mu f` is not explicitly recursive, so that would be valid, and you can use that in, say, Coq. (However, I think that `Mu f` might not be isomorphic to `f (Mu f)`when `f` is not covariant).

Comment: @Labbekak Note that negative/non positive uses of a type variable are allowed, as long as you do not take the fixed point on that. So, in these cases you should not consider whether `f` occurs positively or not. Further, for writing these types, you need higher kinds, and the paper you mention does not consider that (I think).

Comment: Is there an algorithm that I can use to check for (non-strict) positivity of an ADT? I am honestly pretty confused at the moment how to check if an ADT is valid or not. Can I check an ADT or should I check for the specific uses of a type?

Comment: @Labbekak I'm not following you completely. Usually, you take a recursive type definition like `data T x y = K (... (T x' y') ...(T x'' y'')...) | ...` and check whether those occurrences are in positive position. That's it. `Fix` can not be defined according to these rules, even if it could be used on covariant functors, which would cause no harm. `Fix` is disallowed because if we had it we could also use it badly, on noncovariant `f`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! So for every ADT I check that the type constructor only occurs positively and then for each type variable also that they only occur positively? In blogs and answers on this site that I read they always talk about positivity in terms of the type being on the left side of an even amount of arrows. That's why I though Fix was okay since there are no arrows. So any (f (T x y)) where f is a type variable that is a parameter of the data type would be rejected, right? And I guess for mutual recursive data types it would be trickier.

Comment: Hey I just found out that "Inductive bad (r:Type) := Bad : (r -> r) -> bad r." does typecheck in Coq, why is that?

Comment: @Labbekak Because it is not recursive, so all its "bad r" references (there are zero of them) are positive. `Inductive bad (r:Type) := Bad : (bad r -> bad r) -> bad r` instead fails because of the negative recursion.

Comment: But in your answer you are excluding the equivalent Haskell type: "data Bad r = Bad (r -> r)" and you said that all type variables should appear positively. But in the Coq Inductive type the "r" type variables appears negatively. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You can define `Bad r = (r->r)`, there is no problem even if it is not covariant. What you can't do is using `Bad` in a `Fix` or `Inductive` definition to construct a type `T` being equivalent to `T -> T`. In you code `data Bad r` on its own is fine, but when combining it with `Fix` you lose termination.

Comment: Okay, I think I finally understand it now! I really appreciate you took the time to explain it to me!